# OneDrive - Upload file with CURL (or Python) via shareable link

Tags: python, curl, onedrive

I have been given a link to someones OneDrive account to upload a report (file) to the shared folder.  I've tried a few ways via CURL on the command line and I've tried via Python with the requests library, no luck.

Is it possible to upload via the shared link not through a browser? If so, how?

Here's what I've tried...

**cURL**

```
curl -F data=onedrive_testing_v2.txt <URL to shared folder>

curl -d onedrive_testing_v2.txt <URL to shared folder>

curl -v -F filename=onedrive_testing_v2.txt -F upload=@onedrive_testing_v2.txt <URL to shared folder>

curl -X POST \
    '<URL to shared folder>' \
    -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-binary '@onedrive_testing_v2.txt'
```

**Python**

```
import requests
dfile = open("onedrive_testing_v2.txt", "rb")
url = "<URL to shared folder>"
test_res = requests.post(url, files = {"form_field_name": dfile})
if test_res.ok:
    print(" File uploaded successfully ! ")
    print(test_res.text)
else:
    print(" Please Upload again ! ")
```

Note: I'm executing all the curl commands and Python file in the same directory as the file to be uploaded.